# Couldn't update a file in android app assets folder

Tags: android, android-file

I want to update a file in assets folder when the user click a button.

my listener is a classic

```
OnClickListener myUpdateListener = new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        updateAllParams();
    }
};
```

The new file is to an url in this form

`http://sample.test/android/params.dtf`

the file in *assets* folder is

```
params.dtf
```

But I don't know how to do replace this file with the new version on the site.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I want to update a file in the assets folder

No, you cannot.

The assets folder is read-only, you cannot write or update any file present there.

Comment: There is the possibility to use an alternative writable folder to store files such archive, db etc?

Answer (score 4):

You cannot update the assets folder after the application has been packaged and installed. You can, however, store to the device's memory and read in your file from there. More on this subject can be found at http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal

Answer (score 0):

According to me Asset folder is read only.Store your file in sdcard.